Sub-menu position in a simple drop-down menu
Let's assume we have a simple nested menu in HTML:
<ul id="top-menu">
 <li>something
  <ul>
   <li>somethingelse1</li>
   <li>somethingelse2</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li> ... etc.

And equally simple CSS that allows you to display submenus when you move the cursor to any position:


#top-menu ul {
  display: none;
}

#top-menu li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

#top-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#top-menu>li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#top-menu>li>ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  min-width: 150px;
}

#top-menu>li>ul>li {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#top-menu>li>ul>li>ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}
<ul id="top-menu">
  <li>something
    <ul>
      <li>somethingelse1</li>
      <li>somethingelse2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> ... etc.</li>
</ul>



The code above produces a result similar to this (I had my cursor over "Caps"):

As you can see, when I select the “Caps” item, the first submenu item is at the same height as the parent item.
What would I need to fix in the code so that no matter what item on the main menu I select, the first submenu item is at the same height as the first item on the main menu?

To fix this, you can remove the position: relative from #top-menu > li
From this code:
    #top-menu > li {
        position: relative; /* remove this line */
        padding: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

To this code:
    #top-menu > li {
        padding: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

